# can't call servlet from jsp page form

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, submit

I have `JoinCustomerToAccountServlet` servlet under `src/controller` -

```
@WebServlet("/JoinCustomerToAccountServlet")
public class JoinCustomerToAccountServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }

}
```

And  form `joinCustomerToAccount.jsp` under `WebContent/ActionsPages`   -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="JoinCustomerToAccountServlet" method="POST">
            Account join to him : <input type="text" name="account" />
            <input type="submit" value="join" />

</body>
</html>
```

After I fill the form and press on the submit button I get

```
type Status report

message /MyBankProject/ActionsPages/JoinCustomerToAccountServlet

description The requested resource (/MyBankProject/ActionsPages/JoinCustomerToAccountServlet) is not available.
```

It looks like the form searching under his folder and not search for servlet  .

Comment: @WebServlet("/JoinCustomerToAccountServlet") I think this will map the servlet from the root of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your URL mapping is `/JoinCustomerToAccountServlet` and because your JSP resides inside `/MyBankProject/ActionsPages`, you'll have to change your form's action into this:

`<form action="../JoinCustomerToAccountServlet"` to make it work.